# Table structure for user activity feed - relational or not?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, android-activity

So I am stuck on a decision:

I am deciding wether to do something like this for a user activity feed:

```
id | userID | typeID | contentID | time
```

**OR** something more relational with foreign keys and proper indexing like this:

```
id | userID | postID | postCommentID | photoID | photoCommentID | time
```

Or along those lines.

I am looking for an answer which doesn't just say which one but also why and the advantages/disadvantages.

---

**EDIT:**

**Another thing this applies to** is wether using 1 comment table with `type | contentID` or `postID | photoID` is better OR 2 separate tables; one for photo comments and one for post comments??

**EDIT 2:**

*How the data would be used:*

It could be used in 2 scenarios - For displaying in a time line feed for the user themselves or other users around them.

**EDIT 3:**

The reason for choosing this method to create activity feeds even though all the detailed info is stored in other tables is for speed when loading feeds, although I understand I am sacrificing write performance. It also allows for me to add new data/post types later and reduces the number joins in my query to 0.

Thanks for your time!

-Stefan

Comment: If you need activity streams with high performance you could consider looking at an external API like http://www.collabinate.com. Disclaimer - I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

When you say feed - you mean for someone else's consumption?  Or for storing someone else's feed?  Or just a person's activity in your system?

I would normalize first, denormalize as you need to later, but neither of your options show the full story of the scope of what you are modeling.

Comment: it could be used in 2 scenarios - for displaying in a time line feed for the user themselves or other users around them. Sorry pretty tired - working too long! And by normalize you mean use proper structure with Foreign Keys and indexing?

Comment: @Stefan I would design my storage normalized.  It will mean the least impact (locking) during writes.  Which means that writes complete quicker.  Choice of indexes will be for performance.  I'm more expert with SQL Server, but MySQL is very similar (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-physical-record.html), so when you have covering indexes, the data never needs to be read from the data rows.

Comment: @Stefan You don't have an option in MySQL to have materialized views or indexed views, which would be a read optimization.  You could look at read-only denormalized data which is updated periodically or via trigger.  Again, I would normalize first (primary key, foreign key constraints are part of that) and add indexes (part of optimization, although some may be used by particular engines to enforce constraints) and potentially denormalize once you see the actual read patterns.

Comment: @Stefan I would also add that joins are not expensive when they are covered by indexes.  They certainly aren't as expensive as having to write many different places in a denormalized model and potentially having inconsistent data.  Looking at an execution plan will tell you a lot more about the behavior of your common queries during reads.

Comment: Thanks very much for your lengthy answer. I am going to sleep on it and see what a friend of mine has to say as this is just the surface. I think if I was to add foreign keys on all the different columns of activity type to their appropriate parent table this would be pretty "normalized" no? All it would allow is for me to query for the last 10 posts in the activity feed with that userID ... I'm off to sleep, my mind has stopped working! Thanks again!

Comment: @Stefan A foreign key is a constraint which means that a certain column (or columns) is a foreign key to a primary key in another table.  Normalization refers to the process which ensures that the data model is in one of the standard normal forms, which minimize redundancy, and ensure attribute dependency properly.  Just adding constraints or identifying relationships does not mean that a model is in a normal form.